# 10-year Chinese Visa for Green Card Holder?

Tags: visas, china

I'm wondering whether it is possible for me to apply for a 10-year Chinese Tourist Visa as a US Green Card holder? Also, does it help if my wife is a Chinese citizen living in the US as a Green Card holder as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 10 year China visa eligibility is by nationality, not by residence. So you can only get it if China offers it to people of your nationality.

Comment: And adding to this weather your wife is chinese has no baring either

Comment: I was able to confirm with the Chinese Consulate in Los Angeles as well. Thank you for your answer.